# CPT Loop with ACF and passing ID between Loops

Tags: customization, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I have a staging site at:

https://tozsdeforum.ethermedia.hu/

Near the top of the page, we have a "Kiemelt Hirek" section.

In this section, there are five loops in play:

IF (pos1 == true) {display article in top position}
IF (pos2A == true) {display article in second row first position}
IF (pos2B == true) {display article in second row second position}
IF (posyellow == true) {display article in second third row position with yellow bg}
IF (poswhite == true) {display article in second third row position with white bg}

So it displays like this:

Pos1
Pos2A - Pos2B
PosYellow - PosWhite

Now these are implemented with ACF tickers. These work fine, but the request I got from the client is that if the user uploads a new article to pos1, then the older article should automagically go to pos2A, the older article in pos2A should automatically go to pos2B and so on. So they should apply an offset.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to achieve this because these are separate loops. How can I notify the second condition for example:

IF (pos2A == true) {display article in second row first position} that the article in the first loop has updated, and that it needs to change as well to the last article of pos1?

I'm afraid that this is not possible with the current logic, as if the items shifted, then the original ACF records would lose their meaning (for example a ticked pos1 would appear in the second position once a new pos1 article is submitted which would make no sense long-term).

Hope I'm explaining clearly, any help in direction is greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php
echo '<div class="row grey-bordered-boxes cikkek pfstyle ">';
$poststopone = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'cikkek',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'top1_kiemelt_cikk',
            'value' => true,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),

    ),
));

if ($poststopone): ?>
<?php foreach ($poststopone as $post):
    setup_postdata($post);

    ?>

<!--ROW 1 TOP1 Position -->
<article class="item-main col-24 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="cikkek-<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>">
    <div class="item-inner-main">
        <div class="image-blocks-main">
            <a
                href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_id());?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_id(), 'owl_size'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-holder-main">
            <h2 class="entry-title-main"><a
                    href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_id());?>"><?php echo get_the_title(get_the_id()) . ' ' . 'TOP1'; ?></a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

<?php endforeach;?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php
$poststop2a = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'cikkek',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'top2a_kiemelt_cikk',
            'value' => true,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),

    ),
));

if ($poststop2a): ?>
<?php foreach ($poststop2a as $i => $post):
    setup_postdata($post);?>

<!--ROW 2 1/2 A -->
<article class="item-main-half col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="cikkek-<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>">
    <div class="item-inner-main">
        <div class="image-blocks-main">
            <a
                href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_id());?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_id(), 'owl-size'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-holder-main">
            <h2 class="entry-title-main"><a
                    href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_id());?>"><?php echo get_the_title(get_the_id()) . ' ' . 'TOP2A'; ?></a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

<?php endforeach;?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php
$poststop2b = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'cikkek',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'top2b_kiemelt_cikk',
            'value' => true,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),

    ),
));

if ($poststop2b): ?>
<?php foreach ($poststop2b as $i => $post):

    setup_postdata($post);?>

<!--ROW 2 1/2 B -->
<article class="item-main-half col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="cikkek-<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>">
    <div class="item-inner-main">
        <div class="image-blocks-main">
            <a
                href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_id());?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_id(), 'owl-size'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-holder-main">
            <h2 class="entry-title-main item-main-half"><a
                    href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_id());?>"><?php echo get_the_title(get_the_id()) . ' ' . 'TOP2B'; ?></a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

<?php endforeach;?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'cikkek',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        
        array(
            'key' => 'top3a_kiemelt_cikk',
            'value' => true,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        

    )
));



if ($posts): ?>
<?php foreach ($posts as $i => $post):
    setup_postdata($post);
?>

<!--ROW 3 1/2 YELLOW -->
<article class="item-1r1 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 idozitettkiemelt" id="cikkek-<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>">
    <div class="item-inner-1r1">
        <div class="text-holder-1r1 b5">
            <h2 class="entry-title-1r1"><a class="largertext"
                    href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_id());?>"><?php echo get_the_title(get_the_id()) . ' ' . 'TOP3A'; ?></a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

<?php endforeach;?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'cikkek',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        
        array(
            'key' => 'top3b_kiemelt_cikk',
            'value' => true,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        

    )
));

if ($posts): ?>
<?php foreach ($posts as $i => $post):

    setup_postdata($post);
?>
<!--ROW 3 1/2 WHITE -->
<article class="item-1r1 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 idozitettkiemelt" id="cikkek-<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>">
    <div class="item-inner-1r1">
        <div class="text-holder-1r1 b5">
            <h2 class="entry-title-1r1"><a class="largertext"
                    href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_id());?>"><?php echo get_the_title(get_the_id()) . ' ' . 'TOP3B'; ?></a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

<?php endforeach;?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_type' => 'cikkek',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        
        array(
            'key' => 'kiemelt_cikk',
            'value' => true,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        

    )
));

if ($posts): ?>
<?php foreach ($posts as $i => $post):

    setup_postdata($post);
?>

<article class="item-1r1 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 kiemelt" id="cikkek-<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>">
    <div class="item-inner-1r1">
        <div class="text-holder-1r1 p0 b0">
            <h2 class="entry-title-1r1"><a
                    href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_id());?>"><?php echo trim_text(get_the_title(get_the_id()) . ' ' . 'Fehér'); ?></a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

<?php endforeach;?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php
echo '</div>'; ?>
```

Comment: It might be easier to get an answer if you provide actual code, rather than pseudo-code, so people can see how your solutions works now.

Comment: Added the actual code for reference!

Comment: Well, it doesn't make sense because the queries aren't the same... ...you're actually running different meta queries in each slot.

Comment: Thanks Tony, that makes sense. However, if I were to combine the queries into one. -> How can I say in an if statement for example that if new TOP1 articles is published, then move CURRENT TOP1 article to TOP2 position?